# spark driver stopped after getiing result using spark-submit command

Tags: apache-spark-1.5

I have installed spark-1.5.1 standalone mode and using spark-submit command to get result.
Actually i would like to get result using spark hidden rest API.when spark-driver stop,i am not able to get result using rest API.

After dig down using spark-submit,i found that after getting output all the spark-context,driver are stopped.

Can any one please help

Here is the console result:-

result--Lines with a: 60, lines with b: 29
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://182.95.208.242:4040
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
15/11/01 08:46:08 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-a2d4622c-d3c0-447b-aa73-21a3b6af1539
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/11/01 08:46:09 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
ipieawb1@master:~/spark-1.5.1/bin$

I am trying to run simple code e.g

public class SimpleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").
        setMaster("spark://master.genpact.com:7078").set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true");
File tempDir=Files.createTempDir();
tempDir.deleteOnExit();
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
java.util.List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World");
JavaRDD<String> s1 = sc.parallelize(strings);
JavaRDD<String> s2 = sc.parallelize(strings);
// Varargs
JavaRDD<String> sUnion = sc.union(s1, s2);
System.out.println("Union *******"+sUnion.collect());
```

}
}

Comment: Write the result out to disk?

Comment: @climbage ,i have wriiten the result on a specific folder which is under disk.even while getting result on colsole.It stops spark context ,driver and all.

Comment: And what does your code look like?

Comment: code look like-./spark-submit --master spark://cluster:7078 --class classname jarfilepath

Comment: That's not the code, that's the command  to submit the code...

Comment: @climbageI have already put the sample code above.